# Calculating days, hours and minutes difference using asp.vb

Tags: asp-classic

I wan to know who to calculation days, hours and minutes difference in asp. Since i'm new to it its somehow difficult for me. here my code

```
<%

Dim cdate, ddate

cdate = "9/27/2013 4:35:00 PM"

ddate = "9/30/2013 9:35:00 PM"


%>
```

please how do i find the difference between these two dates. precisely days left, hours left and minutes remaining

Answer (score 1):

Use **DateDiff**:

```
fromDate="31-Jan-09 00:00:00"
toDate="31-Jan-10 23:59:00"

document.write(DateDiff("yyyy",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("q",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("m",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("y",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("d",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("w",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("ww",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("h",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("n",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
document.write(DateDiff("s",fromDate,toDate) & "<br />")
```

see this link for the documentation:
http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_datediff.asp

Comment: i've tried it but its not able to write it in days, hours and minutes

Comment: Probably your datatype is still a string and not a valid date? Try using CDate to make shure it's a date: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_cdate.asp